# Input select not working when in bootstrap modal in mobile chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and VueJs 3 & vee-validate 4.
I have an input select in a modal, everything works in desktop but in mobile the select witch is inside the modal is not working in mobile chrome browser, however it works in mobile firefox browser.

When I choose one item in the select menu in mobile chrome browser nothing happen and vee-validate show error.

Note that the other input select that are not in the modals work in mobile chrome browser.

```
<div
        class="modal fade"
        id="attachmentModal"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="attachmentModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="attachmentModalLabel">
                Ajouter une pièce.
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <VeeForm
                class="col"
                v-slot="{ handleSubmit }"
                :validation-schema="attachmentsSchema"
                as="div"
              >
                <form
                  @submit="handleSubmit($event, onAttachmentsSubmit)"
                  id="attachmentForm"
                  ref="attachmentForm"
                >
                  <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="attachmentType" class="form-label"
                      >Type de pièce :</label
                    >
                    <Field
                      name="attachmentType"
                      label="Type de pièce"
                      v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }"
                    >
                      <select
                        class="form-select"
                        id="attachmentType"
                        v-model="attachmentType"
                        v-bind="field"
                        :class="{ 'is-invalid': errorMessage }"
                        aria-label="Default select example"
                      >
                        <option value="">
                          Cliquer pour faire un choix
                        </option>
                        <option
                          v-for="item in attachmentTypes"
                          :key="item.name"
                          :value="item.name"
                          :disabled="item.disabled"
                        >
                          {{ attachmentTexts[item.name] }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </Field>
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="attachmentType"
                      as="div"
                      class="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="attachment" class="form-label"
                      >Sélectionner un fichier :</label
                    >
                    <Field
                      name="attachment"
                      label="Pièce jointe"
                      v-slot="{ handleChange, errorMessage, handleBlur }"
                    >
                      <input
                        class="form-control"
                        id="attachment"
                        :class="{ 'is-invalid': errorMessage }"
                        type="file"
                        accept="application/pdf"
                        @change="handleChange"
                        @blur="handleBlur"
                        aria-describedby="fileHelpBlock"
                        ref="attachment"
                      />
                      <div id="fileHelpBlock" class="form-text">
                        Seulement les fichiers <b>PDF</b> sont acceptés. La
                        taille du fichier ne doit pas dépasser les <b>2 Mo</b>.
                      </div>
                    </Field>
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="attachment"
                      as="div"
                      class="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary d-none"
                    id="submitAttachmentFormButton"
                  >
                    Soumettre
                  </button>
                </form>
              </VeeForm>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-secondary"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Fermer
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                @click.prevent="submitAttachmentForm()"
              >
                Soumettre
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```